# Trying to show a calendar in android app with some other views

Tags: android, calendar

I am a newbie in android. My friend created a CalendarDatePicker class which is working perfectly when I am by pressing a button I can show the calendar class based on onClickListener. Now I want to show this calendar in another activity's screen alongwith some TextViews which will be above and below the calendar. How should I call or load the calendar into this activity so that whenever the activity starts, the calendar appears within activity screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RelativeLayout with `layout_below` attribute to stack your items vertically here is an example:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/upperTxt"
android:text="Some Text Above"
 />
<com.your.calendars.package.CalendarDatePicker
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/calendar"
android:layout_below="@id/upperTxt"
/>
 <TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/lowerTxt"
android:layout_below="@id/calendar"
android:text="Some Text Below"
 />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You'll need to correct the package name for your custom calendar picker class, and add any other Views that you want to the layout. Put this in side of an xml file inside your `layout` folder. Then in your Activity call `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_filename);`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this out and will let you if it works or not.

Comment: It crashes when I try to load the activity. I am getting The class can't be instantiated message in android studio. Tip: use View.isInEditMode() in your customeViews to skip code when shown in the IDE. FYI, I will modify the class so that it can redirect me to some other activity when I select a date.